# Where to increase attachment size of Email in IIS 6.0 or in SMTP service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, windows-server-2008

I am getting following error when my email attachment is bigger than 2 mb

```
Exceeded storage allocation. The server response was: 4.3.1 Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size
```

I want to increase this limit, I searched and found few article ( http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6de966e8-8bcf-4782-95de-466123e59168.mspx?mfr=true )shows that this can be done using

SMTP Server in IIS or in Services. I tried to find that option in both but there is nothing like as they say , simply I did not find any option to increase the size of email/attachment

Can anybody really know how to do it in IIS 6.0

Please avoid giving answers like make zip of your attachment or reduce attachment size or send attachment in two or more pieces.

Comment: it provides the same link http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6de966e8-8bcf-4782-95de-466123e59168.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: http://tvandesijpe.blogspot.com/2011/01/exceeded-storage-allocation-server.html